# Excel VBA Compile Error Else without If

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I try to run a code when column "L" and column "V" stated "Completed" on both. Then column "W" will show "Completed" else it will show "incompleted" but it show compile error "Else withou if".

Below is my code

```
Sub OverallStatus()

Dim x As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

With Sheet1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
         lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                     After:=.Range("A1"), _
                     Lookat:=xlPart, _
                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                     MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastrow = 1
    End If
    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If .Range("L" & x) = "Completed" And .Range("V" & x) = "Completed" Then
        .Range("W" & x) = "Completed"
        Else: .Range("W" & x) = "Incomplete"
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In your case the "Then" must be on the same line as the "If" but it should be the last thing on the line and the part after the "Then" should be on a separate line.  If you put anything after the "Then" on the same line as the "If" then the "If" is a single line statement and then "Else" and "End If" must also be on that same line.

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. It makes the code difficult to read, prevents copying/pasting to test or solve problems, and it's rather rude to users who have limited bandwidth. Copy your code and/or any relevant error messages and paste it as text into your question. Images should only be used when nothing else will work to explain the issue you're having. Please [edit] to include the actual code. (A capture of your entire screen is also in no way relevant to the question asked; you could at least be courteous enough to crop it to the minimal size needed.) Thanks.

Comment: End if should be placed after .range("W" & x) = "Incomplete" ...Not after next

Comment: My apologies, i already updated my code display format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to change on your code:

1. **New line character** after `Then`, or move this back up at end of the `If`
2. Insert **`End If`** before the `Next`
3. Replace `End If` above the `End Sub` with **`End With`**

Comment: I've already updated my code accordingly, but its still showing Else without if error.

Comment: Thank you so much, i just updated the final amendment. Finally it works. Thank you so much for your help.